# Induction proof that $2^m 2^n = 2^{m+n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am unable to proceed with the below claim.

$$2^{m} \times 2^{n} = 2^{m+n}$$

Could anyone let me know how to prove the above claim using induction proof?

I was able to derive proof for odd natural numbers using induction but not able to do the above one.

Comment: What do you know? For example $2\times 2^m=2^{m+1}$ and $2^0=1$ and $a\times b= b\times a$?

Comment: @Henry.. i know the things which you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Let's proceed by induction on $m+n$.

If $m+n=0$, then $m=n=0$ and $2^0\cdot2^0=1=2^{0+0}$.

If $m+n\ge1$, then WLOG $n\ge1$ and
$$2^m\cdot2^n=2^m\cdot2^{n-1}\cdot2\overset{\text{IH}}=2^{m+n-1}\cdot2=2^{m+n}.$$

Comment: @user234215.. I am unable to understand the step2. Could you please explain. What you meant by "WLOG"? Does "IH" above = means Induction hypothesis?

Comment: @TheGaME Yes, IH means Induction Hypothesis and WLOG means Without Loss Of Generality (you can switch $m$ and $n$ if $m\ge 1$). Or you could also just do the same proof for $m\ge 1$.

Comment: @user234215 It is possible to prove the second step for m and n separtely.

Comment: @user234215.. ok got it. I understood it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheGaME You just want to show that it holds for $m+n=K$ assuming it holds for all $m+n<K$. The base step is $K=0$ and for other steps we have $K=m+n\ge 1$. We have to somehow decrease this sum to use the IH, but there are two possibilities. You can't always subtract 1 from $m$ or $n$ if one of them is zero, but there are not two separate induction arguments, it's just one with some branching in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

You may apply the method of Double Induction.

**Sketch of a Solution:-**

> First we fix $m$ and apply induction on $n$. It will be assumed that the Induction basis is already proved because you know $2\times 2^m=2^m\times 2=2^{m+1}$.
>
> Then assuming the statement holds for some $n$ (remember $m$ is fixed)
>   we have,
>
> $$2^m\times 2^n=2^{m+n}\implies 2\times\left(2^m\times
> > 2^n\right)=2\times\left(2^{m+n}\right)\implies \left(2^m\times
> > 2^{n+1}\right)=\left(2^{m+n+1}\right)$$
>
> Can you do the same for $m$, i.e., keeping $n$ fixed apply induction
>   on $m$.
>
> What does proving this gives you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need double induction. Let $m$ be a natural number; we want to prove that, for all natural numbers $n$, $2^m\cdot 2^n=2^{m+n}$

The assertion is true for $n=0$, as $2^m\cdot2^0=2^m\cdot 1=2^m$, while $2^{m+0}=2^m$.

Suppose the assertion is true for $n$. Then
$$
2^m\cdot 2^{n+1}=2^m\cdot(2^n\cdot2)=(2^m\cdot 2^n)\cdot 2
\overset{*}{=}2^{m+n}\cdot2=2^{(m+n)+1}=2^{m+(n+1)}
$$

Therefore $2^m\cdot 2^n=2^{m+n}$ for all $n$. Apply generalization, as we put no restriction on $m$.

The symbol $\overset{*}{=}$ denotes where the induction hypothesis is used. The properties used are those of multiplication and addition, together with the recursive definition of $2^k$ by

- $2^0=1$
- $2^{k+1}=2^k\cdot 2$